# Create and insert temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create and insert temporary table in my sql Version 5.5.27,  temporary table is a table which is turn up when a function or button in myprogram cliqued. So, how to make that temporary table?.

Comment: What language is "myprogram" written in?

Comment: sorry, "my program" is JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide - http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-jdbc-java-to-create-table/170

Essentially you want to execute your create sql using java, heres the main part of the code from the link above:

```
    Connection con = getConnection();
    Statement stmt =null;
    String createString;
    createString = "CREATE TABLE  `mydb`.`employees` ("+
    "`EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',"+
    "`Name` varchar(45) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',"+
    "`Office` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',"+
    "`CreateTime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"+
    "PRIMARY KEY  (`EmployeeID`)"+
     ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;";            
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(createString);
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```